# Why logical shift is called 'logical' shift?

Tags: shift

First I want to clarify my question is not about what is logical shift which I totally understand, but the exact name 'logical' shift itself that has bothered me for years. For arithmetic shift it's quite understandable, the arithmetic property (+/-) is preserved during shift. But how does 'logical shift' have anything to do with 'logic'? What does its name imply?

Comment: Not an answer because I'm _sure_ this is on SE somewhere. http://wiki.schoolcoders.com/gcse/data-representation/numbers/binary-shift/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift discuss the difference, which is basically treating the word/byte/octet/whatever as a bunch of bits, or as a number (possibly with a sign bit).

Comment: cheers mate but unfortunately I still can't get it why on earth such operation is called 'logical'. My only guess is that since anything other than 0 is considered **true** so logical shift doesn't necessarily preserve the leading arithmetic bit as long as there're non-zero bits left after the shift so the whole number remains **true**.

Comment: Just nomenclature. Some people, according to that Wiki article, refer to logical right-shift as "zero-fill right-shift". But there is a long tradition of calling things "arithmetic" and "logical" when those ops refer to storage that is considered a number, and when the storage is considered a collection of bits, respectively.

Comment: Your guess about preserving or not preserving the overall "truth" about a number is probably not quite right. Logical values are passed around as values for convenience, but the actual information is bitwise. It's not that the entire octet carries a single boolean value, but rather a logical shift is intended to work on a collection of bits, each one of which carries useful boolean information.